# Redefine a single operator of a defined type. C++

Tags: c++11, operator-overloading, operators

I want to redefine the bit shift operator on a 64 bit unsigned integer in c++ in such a way that I can do say, `x<<d`, where `x` is a 64 bit integer and `d` is an integer with `|d|<64`, to make it equivalent to `x<<d` for `d>0` and `x>>|d|` for `d<0`.

The only way I know how to do this is to define a whole new class and overload the << operator, but I think that also means I need to overload all the other operators I need (unless there is a trick I don't know), which seems a bit silly considering I want them to behave exactly as they do for the pre-defined type. It's just the bitshift that I want to change. At present, I have just written a function called 'shift' to do this, which doesn't seem very c++ ish, even though it works fine.

What is the stylistically correct way to do what I need?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

If you were able to do this, it would be very confusing to other C++ programmers who read your code and see:

```
int64 x = 92134;
int64 y = x >> 3;
```

And have it behave differently than their expectations, and behave differently from what the C++ standard defines.

The stylistic choice that agrees most with the C++ code I've seen is to continue using your own myshift() function.

```
int64 y = myshift(x, 3);
```

Comment: "Do as the `int`s do."

Answer (score 0):

I think it's very horrible (and I propose it just for fun) but... if you accept to wrap the number of bit shifted in a `struct`...

```
#include <iostream>

struct foo
 { int num; };

long long int  operator<< (const long long int & lli, const foo & f)
 {
   int d { f.num };

   if ( d < 0 )
      d = -d;

   if ( d >= 64 )
      d = 0;

   return lli << d;
 }

int main()
 {
   long long int  lli { 1 };

   std::cout << (lli << foo{+3}) << std::endl;   // shift +3
   std::cout << (lli << foo{-3}) << std::endl;   // shift +3 (-3 -> +3)
   std::cout << (lli << foo{+90}) << std::endl;  // no shift (over 64)
   std::cout << (lli << foo{-90}) << std::endl;  // no shift (over 64)

   return 0;
 }
```